# repr vs str in python classes - both are given

Tags: python, django

I have read and understood the difference between repr and str and noted the difference.

- `repr` - unambigous
- `str` - readable

What happens is both is used? I wrote a simple class and found that repr is called when both are given.

```
class test():

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'repr called'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'str called'


x = test()
print x
```

Now, when I check the implementation of both the classes in Django ValidationError, Im not sure when str will be called as the repr function is already overloaded.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/core/exceptions/#ValidationError

```
def __str__(self):
    # print 'validationerror str'
    if hasattr(self, 'error_dict'):
        return repr(dict(self))
    return repr(list(self))

def __repr__(self):
    # print 'validationerror repr'
    return 'ValidationError(%s)' % self
```

How and when the `__str__` function will be called?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `__str__()` is called for explicit string conversions, i.e. `str(x)` will call `x.__str__()`.  Some functions like `print()` will also perform string conversions of their arguments.

The reason your test code calls `__repr__()` rather than `__str__()` is that the indentation is off – `__str__()` isn't actually part of the class, so it's not called.  Otherwise `print` would perform a string conversion, but `str(x)` falls back to `x.__repr__()` if `__str__()` is not definied.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly on the indentation is off stmt..Both repr and str is part of the class. You can see the code in the link that I provided.

Comment: @user1050619 I think he meant that in your example __str__ has 0 spaces or tabs, while __repr__ has 4 spaces, - it is not a part of your class. But that might be just a sloppy post formatting.

Comment: Thanks..Yes, it’s a formatting issue, corrected it now. @Sven Marnach

Comment: @user1050619 But after fixing this, the code won't call `__repr__()` anymore – [it now calls `__str__()`](https://ideone.com/14AT28).

Comment: @Chiefir I would generally have assumed that this is sloppy post formmatting, but the OP clamed that the code called `__repr__()`, and the exact code they posted actually _did_ call `__repr__()`, so I assumed the issue was real in this case.